# Anroid RxJava2 return value from method

Tags: android, rx-java2

i'm trying to learn RxJava2 and i'm a little disoriented. I try to return a value from the database like in this example :

//  lastOrder - global variable

```
public Order getLastOrder() {
    try {
      Thread thread =   new Thread(() -> lastOrder = ordersDao.getLastOrder());
      thread.start();
      thread.join(); //waiting for result 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastOrderNefin: "+e.toString());
    }
    return lastOrder;
}
```

I tried something with callable but i think i don t understand how this works..

```
 public Order getLastOrder() {
    try {
        Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Order>() {
            @Override
            public Order call() {
                lastOrder = ordersDao.getLastOrder();
                return lastOrder;
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastOrderNefin: "+e.toString());
    }
    return lastOrder;
}
```

Comment: I hope you do not mind me asking. What do you want to actually do? For example in the first example you spawn a Thread, do something and the calling thread is blocked, becuase it is waiting for the spawned thread to join. What are you tryting to accomplish with this? Reactive-Programming (with RxJava) is about not blocking the executing thread and composing async tasks in a neat manner. This is why you would return Single<Order> and not just Order. With will not gain anything by using RxJava the way you try to use it if you do not adapt to the reactive paradigm.

Comment: I'm trying to get something from the room database and i can t do it in the main thread.

Comment: Then your method's signature will never be `public Order getLastOrder()` - it will need to return an async object like a `Single<Order>`, a Future / CompletableFuture, or you provide a callback that should be called when the order is present. The method call itself is synchronous and can't wait if it's on the main thread.